# My program is not working properly

Tags: java

I have the following code in Java but it overflows when it shouldn't. Why?

```
public classO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int big = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println("big = " + big);
        long bigger = big + 2;
        System.out.println("bigger = " + bigger);
    }
}
```

I get this output:

```
 big = 2147483647
bigger = -2147483647
```

Why does it overflow? I have defined bigger as a long. What is wrong?

Comment: You can come up with a better title (more specific describing your problem)

Comment: It's doing integer addition first (associativity of = from R to L) and then assigning to long. You may want to type cast and use that statement as long bigger = (long) big + 2;

Comment: @Sempliciotto: Please consider accepting an answer by clicking the check mark below the vote points if it fixes your problem. Also check your other questions if you could accept and answer. This shows other users that your problem is solved. All your questions have answers but you never accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`big+2` will overflow as big is max. value while `(long) big` not

```
long bigger = (long) big +2
```

will work for you as it will treat big as long instead of integer.
So make a cast of float to it.

Answer (score 4):

`big + 2` is an integer operation and leads to your overflow (first you add two integers and afterwards you cast it to a `long` but at the point of castig the overflow has already happend).

use the following code to create a Long operation by casting your `int` before the add operation:

```
long bigger = (long) big + 2L;
```